# Xamarin iOS - How do you re-layout a view after adjusting height of inline field?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have an iOS project in Xamarin that contains a screen with a complex form in it.

As the user progresses, a UITextfield may be "inserted/revealed" into the view above other fields.  Behind the scenes, all fields are added by default with auto-layout and I am just revealing the field by adjusting its Frame's Height and Y properties.

The issue I have is that the field is appearing in the same space as the field below it and I cannot figure out how to redraw the layout so that the textfields below the newly revealed one will be adjusted down (short of adjusting each field's Frame's Y property).  Below is a simplified mockup with initial-state, issue-state, and desired-state of the UI.

[image: mockup]

Is there an easier way to redraw/reflow the layout of a screen in auto-layout or am I stuck having to adjust the Y property for all lower fields?

(I'll accept answers in Obj-C or Swift as well).

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to mix auto layout and manual layout. This rarely ends well, they aren't meant to coexist in the same view. I suggest you try sticking to one or the other (on a per-view basis). To answer the question in the title though: look into SetNeedsLayout and LayoutIfNeeded.

Comment: SetNeedsLayout did not work.  I ended up having to adjust the Y positioning in the same way I'm adjusting the height on the field that is being revealed.  I agree it's not the best; however, it is better than trying to constantly set the Frame on every ui component on a screen.  And it's still a better experience than splitting a form into multiple screens (which I've been told in other forums to do).  Thanks

Comment: What SetNeedsLayout does is it schedules a layout pass to occur. ViewWillLayoutSubviews gets called on your view controller (if you have one), then auto layout does its magic, then LayoutSubviews gets called on the view, finally ViewDidLayoutSubviews gets called on the view controller (if you have one). So that does re-layout the view, but it depends on your layout code and auto layout constraints being correct for achieving what you want. To tell you the truth I usually prefer manual layout because I like being able to step through the code and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: But for pretty simple views I tend to use auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use autolayout, when **Initial** set the Reveled TextField height constraint 0, when **Desired** change the constraint value that you want or just remove the height constraint.